# Why doesn't the array change when I try to modify it via a for-loop

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I just picked up Python after 3 years in JavaScript, and I'm struggling to understand why the following doesn't change the existing array?

I basically just want to trim each array to the first 5 elements.

```
data = [[1619740800000, '54474.27000000', '108499.98000000', '30000.00000000', '56989.21000000', 
'5.74916200', 1619827199999, '332834.07665858', 23971, '4.30590700', '251576.63190168', '0'], 
[1619827200000, '56989.21000000', 
'105053.04000000', '12000.00000000', '57794.45000000', '10.12076500', 1619913599999, 
'612746.95919066', 45086, '9.12267500', '557156.21495534', '0'], [1619913600000, '57797.36000000', 
'98900.00000000', '30000.00000000', '56539.47000000', '6.05304600', 1619999999999, '334919.15726802', 
 28754, '5.03377800', '284764.41259450', '0']]
```

My for loop:

```
for x in data:
  x = x[:5]

# print(data) outputs the same as above
```

Comment: `data = [x[:5] for x in data]`. the problem is: you can not assign to the elements of your list that way... (`x` will just refer to some of your data, but that `x` has no longer anything to do with your list).

Comment: forgot to add: in this case you might also use a [slice-assignment](https://riptutorial.com/python/example/3048/slice-assignment) in order to modify the nested lists in-place: `x[:] = x[:5]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I'm struggling to understand why the following doesn't change the existing array?"

I take it your actual question is why what you have tried doesn't work, and not specifically how to do it right, but I will address both.

The reason, as I understand it, is that while the `x` variable is, on each iteration assigned the result you are looking for (`x[:5]`) that result is not stored in your `data` array. It is simply stored in the `x` variable, during that single iteration, which is a copy of the element in the array, not a reference to the element itself. It is not the same as doing

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i] = data[i][:5]  # explicitly sets the element
```

which explicitly sets the array elements

As confirmation, see this:

```
data = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]
for x in data:
    x = x[:2]  # does indeed set x, but only x
    print(x)

[1,2]
[5,6]
>> print(data)    # but data array is unchanged
[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]
```

Alternatively, see this (list comprehension):

```
data = [x[:5] for x in data]  
# this creates a new array, and stores it in data, but has the outcome you want
```

Comment: thanks i see. I do like the syntax data = [x[:5] for x in data] , I have used this but I also see why the first example would work by default. Cheers

Comment: The x variable is not local to the code block.

Comment: @Niloct You are right, my mistake, edited

Answer (score 0):

Just do it:

```
data = [[1619740800000, '54474.27000000', '108499.98000000', '30000.00000000', '56989.21000000', 
'5.74916200', 1619827199999, '332834.07665858', 23971, '4.30590700', '251576.63190168', '0'], 
[1619827200000, '56989.21000000', 
'105053.04000000', '12000.00000000', '57794.45000000', '10.12076500', 1619913599999, 
'612746.95919066', 45086, '9.12267500', '557156.21495534', '0'], [1619913600000, '57797.36000000', 
'98900.00000000', '30000.00000000', '56539.47000000', '6.05304600', 1619999999999, '334919.15726802', 
 28754, '5.03377800', '284764.41259450', '0']]

for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i] = data[i][:5]
```